# What could be the cause for remote data corruption when using the google drive android API?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I have createa a small app that reads and writes files using the Google Drive Android API. Locally on one client, everything works fine: I store files using the Drive API, and read them back on the next start without any issues ever. However, when I read the same files on a different device with the same App, the files are corrupted sometimes. The files are JSON files, and the parser complains about missing quotes or braces. If I look at the files using the Google Drive Web interface, I can verify that the file content is not valid. It looks like old content gets partially overwritten with new file content.

Could this somehow be a user issue? I think this may be a Drive API issue because locally, everything is fine, and the API does not seem to provide a way to store invalid data remotely but valid data locally. The first step for filing a bug against the Google Drive API seems to be to get StackOverflow consensus, so I'd also be interested if anybody else is seeing a similar problem.

So my questions are:

1. Can this possibly be a user issue (if so, how)?
2. Has anybody else seen similar problems?

Comment: Hey Stefan, could you file a bug against the Drive Android API on the issue tracker? https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/ It would be great if you could include sample code and reproduction steps if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Will do... Did you run into the same problem? My app saves files after each change, so I am wondering if GDAA just syncs in the middle of a save and then thinks it's done....

Comment: I work on the team. This is the first report of this issue we've had. Committing locally shouldn't have any impact on in progress syncs. Please include sample code in your bug report so we can attempt to reproduce.

Comment: Filed: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3696 Don't have a code example, though (using the regular Java API as a workaround now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to actually have been a Drive API issue, which is fixed now.

For details, see https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3696