# How to avoid from always loading cached app data from Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Currently, I'm using [Google Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro), to store my Android app data, to *Google Drive App Folder*.

This is what I'm doing when saving my application data

1. Generate a checksum for the current local zip file.
2. Search in *Google Drive App Folder*, to see whether there is an existing App Folder zip file.
3. If there is, overwrite the content of existing App Folder zip file, with current local zip files. Also, we will rename existing App Folder zip filename, with the latest checksum.
4. If there isn't existing App Folder zip file, generate a new App Folder zip file, with local zip file's content. We will use the latest checksum as App Folder zip filename.

Here's the code which performs the above-mentioned operations.

### Generate new App Folder zip file, or update existing App Folder zip file

```
public static boolean saveToGoogleDrive(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, File file, HandleStatusable h, PublishProgressable p) {
    // Should we new or replace?

    GoogleCloudFile googleCloudFile = searchFromGoogleDrive(googleApiClient, h, p);

    try {
        p.publishProgress(JStockApplication.instance().getString(R.string.uploading));

        final long checksum = org.yccheok.jstock.gui.Utils.getChecksum(file);
        final long date = new Date().getTime();
        final int version = org.yccheok.jstock.gui.Utils.getCloudFileVersionID();
        final String title = getGoogleDriveTitle(checksum, date, version);

        DriveContents driveContents;
        DriveFile driveFile = null;

        if (googleCloudFile == null) {
            DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(googleApiClient).await();

            if (driveContentsResult == null) {
                return false;
            }

            Status status = driveContentsResult.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                h.handleStatus(status);
                return false;
            }

            driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();

        } else {
            driveFile = googleCloudFile.metadata.getDriveId().asDriveFile();
            DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = driveFile.open(googleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null).await();

            if (driveContentsResult == null) {
                return false;
            }

            Status status = driveContentsResult.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                h.handleStatus(status);
                return false;
            }

            driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();
        }

        OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            int c;

            while ((c = inputStream.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, c);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);
            return false;
        } finally {
            org.yccheok.jstock.file.Utils.close(outputStream);
            org.yccheok.jstock.file.Utils.close(inputStream);
        }

        if (googleCloudFile == null) {
            // Create the metadata for the new file including title and MIME
            // type.
            MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setMimeType("application/zip").build();

            DriveFolder driveFolder = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(googleApiClient);
            DriveFolder.DriveFileResult driveFileResult = driveFolder.createFile(googleApiClient, metadataChangeSet, driveContents).await();

            if (driveFileResult == null) {
                return false;
            }

            Status status = driveFileResult.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                h.handleStatus(status);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle(title).build();

            DriveResource.MetadataResult metadataResult = driveFile.updateMetadata(googleApiClient, metadataChangeSet).await();
            Status status = metadataResult.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                h.handleStatus(status);
                return false;
            }
        }

        Status status;
        try {
            status = driveContents.commit(googleApiClient, null).await();
        } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException e) {
            // java.lang.IllegalStateException: DriveContents already closed.
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);
            return false;
        }

        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            h.handleStatus(status);
            return false;
        }

        status = Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(googleApiClient).await();
        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            // Sync request rate limit exceeded.
            //
            //h.handleStatus(status);
            //return false;
        }

        return true;
    } finally {
        if (googleCloudFile != null) {
            googleCloudFile.metadataBuffer.release();
        }
    }
}
```

### Search for existing App Folder zip file

```
private static String getGoogleDriveTitle(long checksum, long date, int version) {
    return "jstock-" + org.yccheok.jstock.gui.Utils.getJStockUUID() + "-checksum=" + checksum + "-date=" + date + "-version=" + version + ".zip";
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360113/is-java-regex-thread-safe
private static final Pattern googleDocTitlePattern = Pattern.compile("jstock-" + org.yccheok.jstock.gui.Utils.getJStockUUID() + "-checksum=([0-9]+)-date=([0-9]+)-version=([0-9]+)\\.zip", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

private static GoogleCloudFile searchFromGoogleDrive(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, HandleStatusable h, PublishProgressable p) {
    DriveFolder driveFolder = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(googleApiClient);

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705929/filters-ownedbyme-doesnt-work-in-drive-api-for-android-but-works-correctly-i
    final String titleName = ("jstock-" + org.yccheok.jstock.gui.Utils.getJStockUUID() + "-checksum=");
    Query query = new Query.Builder()
            .addFilter(Filters.and(
                Filters.contains(SearchableField.TITLE, titleName),
                Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false)
            ))
            .build();

    DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult = driveFolder.queryChildren(googleApiClient, query).await();

    if (metadataBufferResult == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Status status = metadataBufferResult.getStatus();

    if (!status.isSuccess()) {
        h.handleStatus(status);
        return null;
    }

    MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer = null;
    boolean needToReleaseMetadataBuffer = true;

    try {
        metadataBuffer = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer();
        if (metadataBuffer != null ) {
            long checksum = 0;
            long date = 0;
            int version = 0;
            Metadata metadata = null;

            for (Metadata md : metadataBuffer) {
                if (p.isCancelled()) {
                    return null;
                }

                if (md == null || !md.isDataValid()) {
                    continue;
                }

                final String title = md.getTitle();

                // Retrieve checksum, date and version information from filename.
                final Matcher matcher = googleDocTitlePattern.matcher(title);
                String _checksum = null;
                String _date = null;
                String _version = null;
                if (matcher.find()){
                    if (matcher.groupCount() == 3) {
                        _checksum = matcher.group(1);
                        _date = matcher.group(2);
                        _version = matcher.group(3);
                    }
                }
                if (_checksum == null || _date == null || _version == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                try {
                    checksum = Long.parseLong(_checksum);
                    date = Long.parseLong(_date);
                    version = Integer.parseInt(_version);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "", ex);
                    continue;
                }

                metadata = md;

                break;

            }   // for

            if (metadata != null) {
                // Caller will be responsible to release the resource. If release too early,
                // metadata will not readable.
                needToReleaseMetadataBuffer = false;
                return GoogleCloudFile.newInstance(metadataBuffer, metadata, checksum, date, version);
            }
        }   // if
    } finally {
        if (needToReleaseMetadataBuffer) {
            if (metadataBuffer != null) {
                metadataBuffer.release();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

---

The problem occurs, during loading application data. Imagine the following operations

1. Upload zip data to *Google Drive App Folder* for the first time. The checksum is `12345`. The filename being used is `...checksum=12345...zip`
2. Search for zip data from *Google Drive App Folder*. Able to find the file with filename `...checksum=12345...zip`. Download the content. Verify the checksum of content is `12345` too.
3. Overwrite new zip data to existing *Google Drive App Folder* file. New zip data checksum is `67890`. The existing app folder zip file is renamed to `...checksum=67890...zip`
4. Search for zip data from *Google Drive App Folder*. Able to find the file with filename `...checksum=67890...zip`. **However, after downloading the content, the checksum of the content is still old `12345`!**

### Download App Folder zip file

```
public static CloudFile loadFromGoogleDrive(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, HandleStatusable h, PublishProgressable p) {
    final java.io.File directory = JStockApplication.instance().getExternalCacheDir();
    if (directory == null) {
        org.yccheok.jstock.gui.Utils.showLongToast(R.string.unable_to_access_external_storage);
        return null;
    }

    Status status = Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(googleApiClient).await();
    if (!status.isSuccess()) {
        // Sync request rate limit exceeded.
        //
        //h.handleStatus(status);
        //return null;
    }

    GoogleCloudFile googleCloudFile = searchFromGoogleDrive(googleApiClient, h, p);

    if (googleCloudFile == null) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        DriveFile driveFile = googleCloudFile.metadata.getDriveId().asDriveFile();
        DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = driveFile.open(googleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();

        if (driveContentsResult == null) {
            return null;
        }

        status = driveContentsResult.getStatus();
        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            h.handleStatus(status);
            return null;
        }

        final long checksum = googleCloudFile.checksum;
        final long date = googleCloudFile.date;
        final int version = googleCloudFile.version;

        p.publishProgress(JStockApplication.instance().getString(R.string.downloading));

        final DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        java.io.File outputFile = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = driveContents.getInputStream();
            outputFile = java.io.File.createTempFile(org.yccheok.jstock.gui.Utils.getJStockUUID(), ".zip", directory);
            outputFile.deleteOnExit();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", ex);
        } finally {
            org.yccheok.jstock.file.Utils.close(outputStream);
            org.yccheok.jstock.file.Utils.close(inputStream);
            driveContents.discard(googleApiClient);
        }

        if (outputFile == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return CloudFile.newInstance(outputFile, checksum, date, version);
    } finally {
        googleCloudFile.metadataBuffer.release();
    }
}
```

First, I thought

```
Status status = Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(googleApiClient).await()
```

doesn't do the job well. It fails in most of the situation, with error message `Sync request rate limit exceeded.` In fact, the hard limit imposed in `requestSync`, make that API not particularly useful - [Android Google Play / Drive Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203255/android-google-play-drive-api)

---

However, even when `requestSync` success, `loadFromGoogleDrive` still can only get the latest filename, but outdated checksum content.

I'm 100% sure `loadFromGoogleDrive` is returning me a cached data content, with the following observations.

1. I install a `DownloadProgressListener` in `driveFile.open`, bytesDownloaded is 0 and bytesExpected is -1.
2. If I use [Google Drive Rest API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java), with the following [desktop code](https://github.com/yccheok/jstock/blob/master/src/org/yccheok/jstock/gui/Utils.java#L1225), I can find the latest filename with correct checksum content.
3. If I uninstall my Android app and re-install again, `loadFromGoogleDrive` will able to get the latest filename with correct checksum content.

***Is there any robust way, to avoid from always loading cached app data from Google Drive?***

---

I manage to produce a demo. Here are the steps to reproduce this problem.

### Step 1: Download source code

https://github.com/yccheok/google-drive-bug

### Step 2 : Setup in API console

[image]

### Step 3: Press button SAVE "123.TXT" WITH CONTENT "123"

[image]

A file with filename "123.TXT", content "123" will create in the app folder.

### Step 4: Press button SAVE "456.TXT" WITH CONTENT "456"

[image]

The previous file will be renamed to "456.TXT", with content updated to "456"

### Step 5: Press button LOAD LAST SAVED FILE

[image]

**File with filename "456.TXT" was found, but the previous cached content "123" is read. I was expecting content "456".**

Take note that, if we

1. Uninstall demo app.
2. Re-install demo app.
3. Press button LOAD LAST SAVED FILE, file with filename "456.TXT" and content "456" is found.

I had submitted issues report officially - https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4727

---

### Other info

This is how it looks like under my device - http://youtu.be/kuIHoi4A1c0

I realise, not all users will hit with this problem. For instance, I had tested with another Nexus 6, Google Play Services 9.4.52 (440-127739847). The problem doesn't appear.

I had compiled an APK for testing purpose - https://github.com/yccheok/google-drive-bug/releases/download/1.0/demo.apk

Comment: When I had similar problems a while ago, I ended up using the "regular" Java API as a workaround. Did you consider filing a bug about the requestSync issues -- what you describe above doesn't sound like intended behavior...?

Comment: @StefanHaustein Before Google Play Services, I were using "regular" Java Rest API too. Due to the newly required permission http://stackoverflow.com/a/34701518/72437 in regular Java Rest API, I decide switch over to Google Drive Android API. Now, I realize such decision does more harm than good.

Comment: @StefanHaustein I don't think I want to file a bug report at this moment. As, even when they fix `requestSync` behavior, the strictly imposed limit (Sync request rate limit exceeded) on `requestSync` - http://stackoverflow.com/q/31203255/72437 , make that API not particular useful.

Comment: @StefanHaustein I realize you work in Google. Do you know anyone who is working on Google Drive Android API? Not sure you are able to draw his attention on this question. Would like to hear some input from them :)

Comment: I think we are encouraged to use the official channels (= file a bug) -- which helps ensuring that they actually work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697741/what-could-be-the-cause-for-remote-data-corruption-when-using-the-google-drive-a

Comment: @StefanHaustein ok. Thanks for the link. I'm in the process of producing a minimal workable example to demonstrate the bug. https://github.com/yccheok/google-drive-bug I will let you know once it is done. Thank you very much.

Comment: It seems like your metadata update request is succeeding but the content request is failing, can you try the driveContents.commit request with the metadataChangeset (instead of null)?

Comment: @Shailendra I had modified the code by using driveContents.commit request with the metadataChangeset https://gist.github.com/yccheok/2676fc3383116945ca1fac3bbf5a3b1f The `saveToGoogleDrive` returns true. Still, same problem occurs if you download -> save -> download again. It still get the cached content. I'm still in the process of producing a minimal workable example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Shailendra Helo, I manage to produce a minimal workable example, to demonstrate this problem. Do you mind to take a look? Is there any mistake I had made in the source code, or is this bug in API? Thank you very much.

Comment: @StefanHaustein Helo, I manage to produce a minimal workable example, to demonstrate this problem. Do you mind to take a look in it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you file a bug here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/ ? This will make sure this is routed to the right team.

Comment: @StefanHaustein I hope I had explained the issues in a clear manner - https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4727

Comment: What Android version and device are you running? I tested your demo on Nexus 5 6.0.1 MOB30Y and it is absolutely alright. Did you try to run app on other Drive account?

Comment: @PoprostuRonin I'm using Nexus 5 6.0.1 MOB30Y too. Are you updated with latest Google Play Services? What if you try to click on "Save 123.." and "Save 456.." alternatively multiple times, before clicking on "LOAD LAST SAVED FILE"? Will you get 123.TXT with content "456" (Or 456.TXT with content "123") ?

Comment: @PoprostuRonin May I know, do you only have 1 Google account, or multiple Google accounts in your Nexus 5?

Comment: I have Play services version 9.4.52. Here is a video, me trying to reproduce the bug: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwVbx1E4ikgURDhRa2JXX2FQWFU I tried the same without WiFi and even with *Restrict background data* it didn't break.

Comment: I also tried on multiple accounts the bug did not appear.

Comment: @PoprostuRonin I'm really appreciate your input. This is how it looks like under my device - https://youtu.be/kuIHoi4A1c0 I realize, not all users will hit with this problem. For instance, I had tested with another Nexus 6, Google Play Services 9.4.52 (440-127739847). The problem doesn't appear

Comment: @PoprostuRonin I had compiled an APK for testing purpose - https://github.com/yccheok/google-drive-bug/releases/download/1.0/demo.apk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121373/discussion-between-poprosturonin-and-cheok-yan-cheng).

Comment: Are you logging an error on driveContents.commit? If so, that would indicate that the commit wasn't successful, which would explain the outdated content. Perhaps try committing before you change the metadata.

Comment: Hi @EricKoleda pretty confirm the commit is success. As if it fails, it will return false to the caller. Caller will in turn showing error toast.

Comment: What a rotten design overwriting saved data.  Yeah that's not going to delete everything someday is it when it fails?

Comment: Hi Cheok, I too tried to reproduce but couldn't. Can you try performing the operations in airplane mode? i.e. go offline, save 123, save 456, load and verify if it's 456 or not. If that also produces incorrect result, even the local writes are failing & thus could be related to device storage. Try looking into adb logcat to see if any error messages are reported while saving the file.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng sorry that my answer did not help you.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I'm seeing a similar issue, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183265/google-drive-android-not-returning-latest-version-of-the-file.

There's an important thing, don't know how it affects, though - I have 2 accounts on my Nexus device and I can use either of the in my app to access google drive.

Comment: @Shailendra In my case, I tried the airplane mode. When in the mode, the sync (push the file and pull it back) works fine, same version retrieved. But, when I turn off the airplane mode, some older version is pulled.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I tried your program on my device, it works ok. Nexus 4 Android 5.1

Answer (score 1):

1. Search on Google Drive is slow.
   Why not use properties of the base folder to store id of the zip file?
   https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/properties
2. File names on Google Drive are not unique, you can upload multiple files with same names. The File ID returned by Google, however, is unique.