# Why I always get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: DriveContents already closed."

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I'm in the process of producing a minimal workable example, to demonstrate the bug described in [How to avoid from always loading cached app data from Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934769/how-to-avoid-from-always-loading-cached-app-data-from-google-drive)

I had completed the code at https://github.com/yccheok/google-drive-bug

The code is intent to either update existing text file, or write a new text file.

However, when testing, I always get exception in `driveContents.commit`

```
Status status;
try {
    status = driveContents.commit(googleApiClient, null).await();
} catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException e) {
    // java.lang.IllegalStateException: DriveContents already closed.
    Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    return false;
}
```

The details of the exception is as follow.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: DriveContents already closed.
      at com.google.android.gms.drive.internal.zzv.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.drive.internal.zzv.commit(Unknown Source)
      at org.yccheok.demo.Utils.saveToGoogleDrive(Utils.java:233)
      at org.yccheok.demo.SaveFile123Task.doInBackground(SaveFile123Task.java:13)
      at org.yccheok.demo.SaveFile123Task.doInBackground(SaveFile123Task.java:10)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

---

I had debugged for a long period, and still have no idea why. I don't think I had missed out any steps.

### Correct API key is setup

[image]

### Steps to reproduce the problem

1. Click on `SAVE 123.TXT" WITH CONTENT "123"` button.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Not sure what steps I had missed out, which causes the exception always thrown at this line - https://github.com/yccheok/google-drive-bug/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/yccheok/demo/Utils.java#L233

Thank you.

Comment: Check this documentation about [`DriveContents`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveContents),which states that once the DriveContents instance has been committed, used for creation, or discarded, it becomes closed and any subsequent method call will throw an [`IllegalStateException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html). Also check this [`File Contents`](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files) documentation if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I figure out, I shouldn't call commit after `driveFolder.createFile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveContents

> Once this DriveContents instance has been committed, used for
>   creation, or discarded, it becomes closed and any subsequent method
>   call will throw an IllegalStateException.

I shouldn't call `driveContents.commit` after `driveFolder.createFile`.

I did a fix via https://github.com/yccheok/google-drive-bug/commit/70919dcfe3fd9108c3af9ecf939a6c0ef03e07cc